# How to create inclusion_tag Django?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I'm a Django Beginner.

I've read the documentation, but found no interaction with the DB.

I want display on one page multiple data from DB! 
How to implement it using inclusion_tag with argument(received from html template)?

Please help!

Comment: Are you talking about pagination or just sets of objects in general? Please be clearer with the question

Comment: @Mikeec3 no pagination! I created index page and want display several multiple data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Template tag is the regular django code so you can use the ORM as usual:

```
from myapp.models import Message, Like

@register.inclusion_tag('user_stats.html')
def user_stats(user):
    return {'user': user,
            'messages': Message.objects.filter(user=user).count(),
            'likes': Like.objects.filter(user=user).count()}
```

And then in the `user_stats.html`:

```
User: {{ user.username }} - {{ messages }} message(s), {{ likes }} like(s)
```

**UPDATE**: To pass the data to the template tag just add the argument to the call:

```
{% for user in user_list %}
    <div>
        {% user_stats user %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Ok! How to receive arguments form template tag `{% my_tag "int_argument" %}` ?

Comment: Yes, `{% my_tag 10 %}`.  If the argument is stored in the context variable then you shouldn't use quotes: `{% my_tag int_argument %}`.  If you will use quotes then the template tag will receive the `"int argument"` string instead of the value of the `int_argument` variable.